# HTML 5 ordered lists with duplicate numbers

Tags: html, list, html-lists

Is there a way in HTML 5 to have a list with ties for some of the positions?  Something like this:

```
Rankings
-----------
1. Sam
1. Ben
3. Susan
4. Chris
```

number 1 had to repeat because there was a tie, then the list skips to number 3. The 1 to the left of Ben could disappear too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-li-element.html#attr-li-value) for the purpose:

```
<ol>
<li>Sam
<li value=1>Ben
<li value=3>Susan
<li>Chris
</ol>
```

To make the number disappear, you would use CSS, e.g.

```
<li style="list-style-type: none">Ben
```

Answer (score -3):

Or, how about an html5 list that starts with lowercase alpha lettering and moves to a nested list of lowercase roman numberals. It should go something like this:

```
<ol type="a">

    <li>This item one</li>

    <li>Item two

        <ol>

            <li  type="i">First sub paragraph of item 2</li>

            <li>Second sub paragraph of item 2</li>

            <li>Third sub paragraph of item 2</li>

        </ol>
    </li>

    <li>Item 3</li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Downvoting, as this does not answer the question.